# How to loop over a text file (to remove tags and normalize) using python

Tags: python, loops, nlp, python-3.8, normalize

I am trying to loop over a text file to remove tags, punctuation, stopwords. I have already used Python 3.8.3 Beautiful Soup to scrape the text (newspaper articles) from the site. It returns a list that I saved as a file. However, I am not sure how to use a loop in order to process all the items in the text file.

In the code below  I have used  listfilereduced.text(containing data from one news article,  [link to listfilereduced.txt here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojwN4u8cmh_nUoMJpdZ5ObaGW5URYYj3/view?usp=sharing)), however I would like to run this code on listfile.text(containing data from multiple articles, [link to listfile.text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V3s8w8a3NQvex91EdOhdC9rQtCAOElpm/view?usp=sharing)). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. The text is in a Non-English script, but the tags are all in English.

```
#This text file contains just one news item

with open('listfilereduced.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as my_file:
    rawData = my_file.read()
    print(rawData)

#Separating body text from other data

articleStart = rawData.find("<div class=\"story-element story-element-text\">")
articleData = rawData[:articleStart]
articleBody = rawData[articleStart:]
print(articleData)
print("*******")
print(articleBody)
print("*******")


#First, I define a function to strip tags from the body text

def stripTags(pageContents):
    insideTag = 0
    text = ''

    for char in pageContents:
        if char == '<':
            insideTag = 1
        elif (insideTag == 1 and char == '>'):
            insideTag = 0
        elif insideTag == 1:
            continue
        else:
            text += char
    return text

#Calling the function

articleBodyText = stripTags(articleBody)
print(articleBodyText)

 
#Isolating article title and publication date

TitleEndLoc = articleData.find("</h1>")
dateStartLoc = articleData.find("<div class=\"storyPageMetaData-m__publish-time__19bdV\">")
dateEndLoc=articleData.find("<div class=\"meta-data-icons storyPageMetaDataIcons-m__icons__3E4Xg\">")
titleString = articleData[:TitleEndLoc]
dateString = articleData[dateStartLoc:dateEndLoc]


#Call stripTags function to clean
articleTitle= stripTags(titleString)
articleDate = stripTags(dateString)

print(articleTitle)
print(articleDate)

#Cleaning the date a bit more

startLocDate = articleDate.find(":")
endLocDate = articleDate.find(",")
articleDateClean = articleDate[startLocDate+2:endLocDate]
print(articleDateClean)


#save all this data to a dictionary that saves the title, data and the body text 
PAloTextDict = {"Title": articleTitle, "Date": articleDateClean, "Text": articleBodyText}
print(PAloTextDict)

#Normalize text by: 

#1. Splitting paragraphs of text into lists of words
articleBodyWordList = articleBodyText.split()
print(articleBodyWordList)


#2.Removing punctuation and stopwords

#https://bnlp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

from bnlp.corpus import stopwords, punctuations

#A. Remove punctuation first

listNoPunct = []

for word in articleBodyWordList:
    for mark in punctuations:
        word=word.replace(mark, '')
    listNoPunct.append(word)
print(listNoPunct)



#B. removing stopwords
banglastopwords = stopwords()
print(banglastopwords)
 
cleanList=[]
for word in listNoPunct:
    if word in banglastopwords:
        continue
    else:
        cleanList.append(word)
print(cleanList)
```

Comment: If you are not using BeautifulSoup to parse your HTML, you should.  You would tell it "find all <div> tags with class story-element-text", and it will return a list to you, which you can process one by one.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did that already it returned a list (I've edited my original post to clarify) that I saved as a text file. I am not sure how to loop through multiple elements of the text file. The above code does it for one article only.

Comment: Assuming there's one result per line, you don't want to read the whole file.  Do `with open(...) as my_file:` / `....for rawData in my_file:` and have your find and prints inside that loop.

Comment: Removing the tags is as simple as `re.sub('<[^>]*>','',line)`.